# Modulos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

me encuentro practicando con los modulos en JavaScript y me encontraba realizando una pequeña practica con la api de open weather. Mi consulta seria como podria hacer para agregar un boton y que me muestre la temperatura en esa unidad(sea celsius(por defecto),kelvin o fahrenheit), y me lo reemplace en el momento por la temperatura que haya en pantalla.
Adjunto código. Agradezco su ayuda.

`
    intefaz.js

```
export const formulario = document.querySelector('#formulario-buscar');
export const divBuscar = document.querySelector('#buscar');
export const divMensajes = document.querySelector('#mensajes');
export const divResultado = document.querySelector('#resultado')
export const buttonKelvin = document.querySelector('#kelvin');
```

api.js

```
export class Api{
constructor(ciudad,key){
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.key = key;
}
async obtenerCiudad(){
    const ciudad = await 
fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=${this.ciudad}&appId=${this.key}`);
    const obtener = await ciudad.json();
    return{
        obtener
    };

    }
    }
```

`

`
         app.js

```
    import * as UI from './interfazClima.js';
    import { Api } from './apiClima.js';


   UI.formulario.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
   e.preventDefault();

const ciudad = document.querySelector('#ciudad').value;

if(ciudad === ''){
    UI.divMensajes.innerHTML = '<h2>Ingrese una ciudad</h2>';
    UI.divMensajes.classList.add('error');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        UI.divMensajes.innerHTML = '';
        UI.divMensajes.classList.remove('error');
    },2500)
}else{
    const api = new Api(ciudad, "35fc292c3edbb27c45dc522f8ca57d06");
    api.obtenerCiudad()
        .then((data)=>{
            //console.log(data);
            if(data.obtener.cod === 200){
              const temperatura = ('Actualmente hay ' + 
      (data.obtener.main.temp - 273.15).toFixed(2) + ' Grados Celsius');
               UI.divResultado.textContent = temperatura;
               UI.divResultado.style.textAlign = 'center';
               UI.divResultado.style.color = 'brown';
               UI.divResultado.style.fontSize = '20px';
               //UI.formulario.reset();
            }else{
                UI.divMensajes.innerHTML = '<h2>Ciudad no encontrada.... 
           </h2>';
                UI.divMensajes.classList.add('error');
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    UI.divMensajes.innerHTML = '';
                    UI.divMensajes.classList.remove('error');
                    UI.formulario.reset();
                },2500);
            }
        });
       }
    });
   UI.buttonKelvin.addEventListener('click',()=>{

   });
```

`